# Connect to WPA2 enterprise at College using wicd on Linux

Tags: networking, network-manager, 17.10, wicd, wpa2

I'm having trouble connecting to my College Wi-fi network with Ubuntu 17.10 Network Manager. I know it is not the best manager that exist (could be the worst lol), but I'm not able to connect to that network using wicd. At home, I can perfectly connect, and it is fast. But, when I try to use wicd, I don't know which template I have to use. I've tried a lot of them that I find at the Internet, but no one worked.

I'm using a HP laptop with BCM943142Y adapter. I think this is not important using a template on wicd, but any info I can give to you all will be not in vain. (BTW, network is not "eduroam").

To connect the network it is needed:

```
WPA2
AES
EAP-TTLS-PAP
CA certificate
Authentification
```

I will be very thankful to all incoming help.

Regards!